# Xcopy files and folders into a new folder within the source folder

Tags: xcopy

I have a little structure like this:

```
[ ] root
 |  
 +---- text.txt
 +-[ ] folder
 +-[ ] copy
```

Now I'd like to copy all contents (including `folder` and its possible contents) of `root` into `copy` with Xcopy.

**How would I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do as you ask, you could do it this way:

```
xcopy root root\copy /E
```

However, I would not advise that, because you would be making copies of copies since copy is a folder under root.

I would advise a different structure whereby copy is at the same level as root, and you could:

```
xcopy root root_copy /E
```

The documentation can be found at various places, depending on your operating system, such as:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289483
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx
http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true

Here's what I typically use:

```
xcopy src dest /Q /H /E /I /Y
```

/Q - Does not display file names while copying.

/H - Copies hidden and system files also.

/E - Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones. Same as /S /E. May be used to modify /T.

/I - If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory.

/Y - Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.